# Specify the -jar option in the file association Windows 8, Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, windows-8, jar, file-association

I'm following this guide on how to make your program in Netbeans into a standalone executable that can be distributed:https://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html#troubleshooting

I cleaned and built the project in Netbeans, then tried double clicking the .jar in the dist folder of the project folder, but nothing happened.  I then ran the project through the command line, going to the dist folder of the project and then typing java -jar "FileName.jar", and it ran perfectly fine.

The .jar file in the dist folder has a java logo, so I assume that it's not because of the first reason in the "Troubleshooting JAR File Associations" section of that guide.  I suspect that it's because of the second reason.

And here's where I need help.  I've tried following the path that they give, but I'm running Windows 8 and I can't find the "File Types" tab in "Folder Options", and so I can't go any further.  Anyone know what to do?

Comment: Update: I was kind of able to find what they specified in the guide under "Default Programs --> Set Associations", but I can't edit the command used to execute the file.

Answer (score 0):

See "[how to run .jar file by double click on windows 7 (64)](/questions/8511063/how-to-run-jar-file-by-double-click-on-windows-7-64)", "[jar file doesn't open upon double click](/questions/9259389/jar-file-doesnt-open-upon-double-click)", "[Running Jar file in Windows](/questions/394616/running-jar-file-in-windows)", and probably a few other answers here on StackOverflow.

From NetBeans.org, see the "[Troubleshooting JAR File Associations](http://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html#troubleshooting)" section of the "[Packaging and Deploying Desktop Java Applications](http://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html)" knowledgebase article.